# How does explorer know what tortoisesvn overlay handler to use?

Tags: c++, tortoisesvn, overlay

I'm writing an app in C# that will have a com object to display overlay images in windows explorer similar to tortoise. While looking at the C++ source I understand how to make and register a overlay handler but I can't find where does it get the object state variable to determine what image to display. I know how to get a regular file info from metadata but I don't know how to do it with custom attributes like conflicted or locked in tortoise case since I read somewhere you can't add custom metadata to files.

Comment: Does tortoisesvn **installer** tell Windows Explorer which overlay to use?

Comment: Not exactly sure what are you asking, im using code from https://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/source/browse/. It registers it handlers, i cant find how does it determine witch one to display